# Android Studio for Dart without emulator

Tags: android-studio, dart

Is it possible to use AndroidStudio (for Dart) withOUT running an emulator?

Context:  I am a complete newbie and have started reading some intro books and following online tutorials. I am aiming to learn DART and FLUTTER and have successfully installed AndroidStudio and an emulator and ran some successful test projects like helloworld.

The thing is, these early example projects are VERY basic things, to teaches me about variables and syntax etc and outputs results to the console. At this point, i do not need to boot up an entire emulator (which adds a layer of clunkiness when running)... but AndroidStudio seems to *insist* on one being activated?

I could use "DartPad" (which i love) for simple stuff - but it's limited and i'd prefer to learn one dedicated IDE if possible.

Comment: you can run any file that contain the main method, by right clicking on the file -> run fileName.

Comment: This doesn't work because it requires an emulator to be running. Says error "No Connected Devices Found" My question is, can i run code for output in the console without having an emulator running?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are actually running. If you are using Dart alone, you should be able to run it. Personally, I do these kinds of projects within IntelliJ Idea - which Android Studio is based on anyway, but doesn't come with the Android "overhead". Microsoft Visual Studio Code is another valid option that many people use.

If your project is based on Flutter (i.e. it contains UI), you need a "device" to run on - it might be the Android emulator, iOS simulator, Chrome or native (experimental).

Comment: Thanks, and yes that is what i would expect too - if not using flutter elements then no need for the android emulator. But for the life of me i can't figure out how to make it work without the emulator...